# View the actual source code of an AJAX page

Tags: ajax, dom, dhtml

Here's an example:

https://www.namecheap.com/domains/domain-name-search/results.aspx?domain=whateverstacks&tlds=com&type=single&

The page takes a few seconds before it updates and lets us know the domain in question is available.

But if I view the source code in firefox, even after the page is fully loaded, the following text is nowhere to be found:

```
whateverstacks.com is available from just $10.69/yr*
```

How can I view the *actual* source code of the present web site (rather than only the HTML code that was present before the page fully loaded)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the browser's built-in dev tools, or [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/html).

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to do it programatically? For instance if I wanted to check and see if that domain is available every five minutes, I wouldn't want to use firebug each time..

Comment: Yes, you can do it programmatically, but in general scraping HTML is a pretty terrible way to do this sort of thing. What you're looking for is an HTTP API.

Answer (score 1):

You need to inspect the page elements which are being rendered, rather than simply looking at the page's original source. I believe Firefox's developer tools are capable of this, as well as extensions such as Firebug.

Google Chrome is capable of this directly from the context menu; right click on the element you want to inspect and choose "Inspect Element".

Comment: Is there a way to do it programatically? For instance if I wanted to check and see if that domain is available every five minutes, I wouldn't want to use firebug each time..

Comment: @some1, Most probably, but I've never tried scraping an AJAX page myself.

Answer (score -2):

You can't. Web-pages are output of application code on the server. If the "application code" is a HTML page, it is sent to you unchanged.

Most browsers allow you to look at the generated code, if the webpage is written in javascript. In Chrome, this can be inspected using the developer console, in Firefox, it's firebug.

The actual asmx code in your case resides on the server and you need access to the source files to have a look.

Comment: Thank you :-), at least one who reads a comment if it changes.

Answer (score -3):

In chrome inspect the element and then right click on the element in elements tab and select "edit as html".
This will show you the raw content